# PHP Job queueing: One uber-worker/dispatcher or many smaller workers?

Tags: php, message-queue, jobs, worker, beanstalkd

I'm starting to use asynchronous jobs/messages to do some heavy background work on a PHP page instead of making the user sit there and wait for it. So far I'm leaning towards using Beanstalkd over RabbitMQ or Amazon's SQS, but my question below is a bit more generic and applies to all of them:

Is it better to have one huge worker acting as a dispatcher for multiple job types?

- Worker watches all jobs, delegates based on job type
- Only one open connection to Beanstalkd
- Use meta-data to dispatch Worker objects to do the actual work?
- May only process 1 job at a time on the server

Or is it better to have several, smaller focused worker scripts on the same server?

- Each worker only watches 1 kind of job
- Multiple, sustained connections to Beanstalkd
- Less complexity, as each script only does one thing
- Other job types don't clog up while waiting for one long job to run
- Takes more resources

There are probably several other factors that I don't even know about, so any additional tips would be appreciated.

(If it matters, I'm planning to daemon-ize a PHP-based worker script using Supervisor. For now the worker will only be running on 1 server but that may expand to two in the future...)